# How to show the toolbar in a fragment depending on the checkbox clicked in adapter in android?

Tags: java, android, gridview, checkbox

I am trying to show a `toolbar` only when the `checkboxes` on the gridview are clicked. I have a checkbox listener in the adapter.

Comment: You want to add dynamically or just want to toggle visibility

Comment: Sorry, I found a solution for this. thanks for responding though